# owncloud error "App directory not found!"

Tags: owncloud

I'm currently using on cloud to create a cloud, and I keep getting these errors.

App directory "/home/bluesvisor/www/oc3/apps" not found! Please put the ownCloud apps folder in the ownCloud folder or the folder above. You can also configure the location in the config.php file.

And this is 'config.php'.

```
'datadirectory' => '/home/bluevisor/www/oc201/data',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'http://test3.mydomain.kr',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '10.5.0.10',
  'dbname' => 'ocdb201',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'root',
  'dbpassword' => 'password',
  'logtimezone' => 'UTC',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/home/bluevisor/www/oc201/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/home/bluevisor/www/oc201/apps-external',
      'url' => '/apps-external',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
```

The error "not found" appears, but the directory is well located in that path. I searched, but there weren't many articles about the error.I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: The 2nd part of the message is of interest: Please put the ownCloud apps folder in the ownCloud folder or the folder above.

Where is your ownCloud directory?

Comment: OK, the path exists, but is it owned by www-data or the user running the web server and does he have access to it?